# Are there account age or level requirements for obtaining special research?

Tags: pokemon-go

My coworker created his account about a week ago and only got three special research tasks. The newest one, "A Thousand Year Slumber", was not among them.

What are the specific requirements for getting special research tasks?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/specialresearch.shtml) about "A Thousand Year Slumber,"

> You can only start it after you've completed Part 3 of the "A Mythical Discovery" Special Research

Completing Part 3 also unlocks "A Ripple In Time."

Reaching trainer level 10 will unlock "Jump Start," but it must be unlocked by 2019-09-02.